# Entity framework better way to reduce lambda condition WHERE?

Tags: entity-framework

I had the code below that provide search, 4 field, the 
lambda will increase huge lot for each field included in, and it is time consuming and not efficient to have such a combination search, any better way to write a proper search?

```
var result = db.ValuePairs
.Where(c=>
(isStatus && isText && isCode && isGroupCd)
?
c.Status == status && c.Text == text && c.Code == code && c.GroupCode == groupCd
:
(isStatus && isText && isCode)
?
c.Status == status && c.Text == text && c.Code == code
:
(isStatus && isText && isGroupCd)
?
c.Status == status && c.Text == text && c.GroupCode == groupCd
:
(isStatus && isCode && isGroupCd)
?
c.Status == status && c.Code == code && c.GroupCode == groupCd
:
(isText && isCode && isGroupCd)
?
c.Text == text && c.Code == code && c.GroupCode == groupCd
:
(isStatus && isText)
?
c.Status == status && c.Text == text
:
(isStatus && isCode)
?
c.Status == status && c.Code == code
:
(isStatus && isGroupCd)
?
c.Status == status && c.GroupCode == groupCd
:
(isText && isCode)
?
c.Text == text && c.Code == code
:
(isText && isGroupCd)
?
c.Text == text && c.GroupCode == groupCd
:
(isCode && isGroupCd)
?
c.Code == code && c.GroupCode == groupCd
:
(isStatus)
?
c.Status == status
:
(isText)
?
c.Text == text
:
(isCode)
?
c.Code == code
:
(isGroupCd)
?
c.GroupCode == groupCd
:
groupCd != ""
);
```

Comment: Please fix your tags. `Linq-to-SQL` and `Entity-Framework` are mutually exclusive techs.

Comment: Sorry for that, the tag had changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple boolean logic there...

```
.Where(c =>
      (!isStatus || c.Status == status)
     && (!isCode || c.Code == code)
     && (!isGroupCd || c.GroupCode == groupCd)
);
```

Comment: aiks, never thought it can be that simple, although did see the same code as above, but never think of using it, thanks